# buildozer-kivy app not working on phone, what is the problem?

Tags: android, kivy, google-colaboratory, buildozer

After app got packaged I tried downloading it on phone using package installer, I tried a lot of times and followed tutorials on how to solve this problem but it didn't work which why I am sure it's a problem in buildozer, I am using cython 0.29.21, libffi7, note: I am using python3.

list of warnings I had during the build:

```
[WARNING]: prerequisites.py is experimental and does not support all prerequisites yet.
[WARNING]: Please report any issues to the python-for-android issue tracker.
[WARNING]:Using flatDir should be avoided because it doesn't support any meta-data formats.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[DEBUG]:Unable to strip the following libraries, packaging them as they are: libSDL2.so, libSDL2_image.so, libSDL2_mixer.so, libSDL2_ttf.so, libcrypto1.1.so, libffi.so, libmain.so, libpybundle.so, libpython3.10.so, libsqlite3.so, libssl1.1.so.
[DEBUG]:Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
```

List of commands I used to set up the conversion:

1. !pip install buildozer
2. !pip install cython==0.29.21
3. !lsb_release -a
4. !sudo apt-get install -y 
   python3-pip 
   build-essential 
   git 
   python3 
   python3-dev 
   ffmpeg 
   libsdl2-dev 
   libsdl2-image-dev 
   libsdl2-mixer-dev 
   libsdl2-ttf-dev 
   libportmidi-dev 
   libswscale-dev 
   libavformat-dev 
   libavcodec-dev 
   zlib1g-dev
5. !sudo apt-get install -y 
   libgstreamer1.0 
   gstreamer1.0-plugins-base 
   gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
6. !sudo apt-get update
   !sudo apt-get install libtool
7. !sudo apt-get install build-essential libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 bzip2 libbz2-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev openssl libgdbm-dev libgdbm-compat-dev liblzma-dev libreadline-dev libncursesw5-dev libffi-dev uuid-dev libffi7
8. !sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
   !sudo apt-get install libffi7
9. !sudo apt install build-essential autoconf libtool
10. !buildozer init

    > then add this ,kivymd to requirements into buildozer.spec file like this:
    > requirements = python3,kivy,kivymd
11. !buildozer -v android debug